# Rubymine RSpec kind of error after successful test

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, spork

I am a newbie just learnt how to use RSpec. My RSpec works fine in windows terminal. However, in Rubymine build-in RSpec. It errors after giving success message. Which is really annoying.

Git:  https://github.com/ivawzh/sample_app

Please help.

Thanks and best regards.

RSpec works fine in native cmd
[image: cmd]

Not sure if this matters, this is the Spork drb server
[image]

Rubymine build-in RSpec, it says the tests are passed. But errors come after success message.
[image]

[image]

Error messages:

```
Running specs...
Command line: 
["C:\\Ruby200\\bin\\ruby.exe", "-e", "$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)", "C:\\Ruby200\\bin/rspec", "--require", "teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter", "--format", "Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter", "E:/RoR docs/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb", "--drb", "--backtrace"]

2 examples, 0 failures, 2 passed

Finished in 0.17701 seconds
  <-- Slave(1) run done!
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner': Command failed with status (1): [C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=tr...] (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.2/rb/testing/runner/specs_in_folder_runner.rb:139:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Environment:

```
Ruby version    2.0.0 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version    2.0.2
Rack version    1.5
Rails version   4.0.0
Environment development
Database adapter    postgresql
```